# Treat string as binary and do binary manipulation in perl

Tags: string, perl, binary, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have two strings in perl

```
$a = "10001";
$b = "10101";
```

I need to find bitwise xor of these two strings i.e.

```
$a XOR $b = "00100";
```

How should I do this in perl ?

Answer (score 4):

To [xor two numbers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or):

```
my $n1 = 0b10001;
my $n2 = 0b10101;
my $n = $n1 ^ $n2;
say sprintf '%05b', $n;
```

To xor two numbers (starting from string form):

```
my $n1 = '10001';
my $n2 = '10101';
my $len = max map length, $n1, $n2;
my $n = oct("0b$n1") ^ oct("0b$n2");
say sprintf '%0*b', $len, $n;
```

To [xor two strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators): (any length, as long as it's the same for both strings):

```
my $n1 = '10001';
my $n2 = '10101';
my $n = ($n1 ^ $n2) | ("\x30" x length($n1));
say $n;
```

To xor two strings: (any length):

```
my $n1 = '010001';
my $n2 = '10101';
my $len = max map length, $n1, $n2;
$n1 = substr((" " x $len).$n1, -$len);
$n2 = substr((" " x $len).$n2, -$len);
my $n = ($n1 ^ $n2) | ("\x30" x $len);
say $n;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [oct](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html):

> If EXPR starts off with `0b`, it is interpreted as a binary string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my ($x, $y) = map oct "0b$_", qw(10001 10101);
printf "%08b\n", $x ^ $y;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are declaring the information yourself, you can use a bit literal:

```
my $first = 0b10001;
my $second = 0b10101;

my $xored = $first ^ $second;

if ($xored == 0b00100)
{
    print "Good!";
}
```

Works with numbers and hex too:

```
my $first = 21;    # or 0b10101 or 0x15
my $second = 0x11; # or 0b10001 or 17

my $xored = $first ^ $second;

if ($xored == 0b00100) # or == 4,  or == 0x04 
{
    print "Good!";
}
```

As an aside, you should also avoid using `$a` and `$b`, as they have a special meaning for the `sort` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this subroutine:

```
sub bin2dec {
    return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
}
```

It will convert the strings to integers, and you can use the bitwise XOR `^` on them, then test if that equals 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a few functions that does the one-bit operation:

```
sub xor
{
   my $p = shift;
   my $q = shift;

   return ( $p eq $q ) "0" : "1";
}
```

then you could call this successfully for each pair of characters (each successive bit).

```
for (my $index = 0; $index < inputLength; $index++)
{
     $result = $result . xor ( substr ($a, $index, 1), substr ($b, $index, 1) );
}
```

Where `inputLength` is the length of `$a` and `$b`.
This is one way of doing it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As far as $a and $b have a fixed length, say 5:

```
 $a = '00011';
 $b = '00110';
 $xor = ($a ^ $b) | '00000';
```